# failure in connceting to NFS server?

Tags: nfs, vmware-vsphere, datastore

whe i try to create a NAS datastore(shareing_datastore) in vmware-vsphere , I have this error always

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The host can't mount the NFS share is all - the problem is either;

1. There's no valid route from host to NAS - ssh into the host and ping the NAS, or the other way around if you can.
2. There's a firewall in the way of them blocking NFS ports - this could be an external firewall or perhaps ESXi's built-in firewall, check this in the host's security tab.
3. The share isn't set correctly - check that the host's IP is within the NFS share's scope, probably best to do this on the NAS or do a 'showmount -e {NAS IP}' on another machine in the same VLAN as the NAS.
4. You could be forming the mount name incorrectly - difficult to help with this without the output of the 'showmount' command above.
5. If you're using NFSv4 then there could easily be permission issues - again we'd need to know the share's setup for that though.